# Error loading controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure why as I am running code straight off of a template. Does anyone see something in the stack trace that I don't? It is posted below.

> Server Error in '/Cfia.Web.MvcTemplate.Example' Application.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned
>   an error: (404) Not Found.
>
> Source of Error:

```
Line 27:         /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ApplicationBaseController" /> class.
Line 28:         /// </summary>
Line 29:         public ApplicationBaseController()
Line 30:         {
Line 31:             ApplicationTitle = Labels.GetLabel("Application.MvcTemplate.Examples");
```

> Stack Trace:
>
> [WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.] 
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +8521152
>   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials
>   credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) +160
>   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type
>   ofObjectToReturn) +328
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +75
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData) +260
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
>   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack,
>   ContextCallback callback, Object state) +118
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +7534355
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +187
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace) +176    System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader) +144    System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) +205
>   Cfia.Globalization.Provider.XmlFileLabelProvider.RetrieveAllLabels(CultureInfo
>   culture) +424
>   Cfia.Globalization.Provider.LabelService.RetrieveAllRawLabels(CultureInfo
>   culture) +490
>   Cfia.Globalization.Provider.LabelService.RetrieveAllLabels(CultureInfo
>   culture) +50
>   Cfia.Globalization.Provider.LabelService.Labels(CultureInfo culture)
>   +344    Cfia.Globalization.Labels.GetLabels(CultureInfo culture) +157    Cfia.Web.Mvc.Menu.FooterLink..ctor() +221
>   Cfia.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.BaseController..ctor() +165
>   Cfia.Web.MvcTemplate.Example2.Controllers.ApplicationBaseController..ctor()
>   in c:\Users\cir-anglinovd\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\ContosoUniversity\Cfia.Web.MvcTemplate.Example2\Controllers\ApplicationBaseController.cs:29
>   Cfia.Web.MvcTemplate.Example2.Controllers.HomeController..ctor() in
>   c:\Users\cir-anglinovd\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\ContosoUniversity\Cfia.Web.MvcTemplate.Example2\Controllers\HomeController.cs:30
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +256    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +92
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type
>   'Cfia.Web.MvcTemplate.Example2.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure
>   that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +562491
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +89
>   Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IControllerFactory_CreateController.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
>   +155    Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +116    Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext
>   context) +71    Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +604 
>   Castle.Proxies.IControllerFactoryProxy.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +193
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +305    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__2() +78    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
>   +19    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +128
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +12551795    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: Odds are you are not hitting the controller method. The error code is from IIS meaning that the URL is probably wrong.

Comment: What do you mean that the URL is probably wrong? You think it doesn't match a valid route defined in the route table?

Comment: You need to show the code where you get the error as well.

Comment: I think you need to provide the `ApplicationBaseController` constructor code and after that what is `Labels`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, just had to make some changes in the web.config file.